# What guarantees a process monitor stays running?

Tags: supervisord

It is common when deploying Web applications to use something like supervisord or circus to keep all your processes up and running.  But how do you ensure that these programs are running?  In other words, who will watch the watchers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans are watchers for tools like supervisor. There are 3rd party plugins like [supervisord-monitor](https://github.com/mlazarov/supervisord-monitor) which provide UI for monitoring.

But humans cannot monitor 24/7. So supervisor has evenlistners. You can use plugins like superlance to monitor supervisor process. When a process stops/exits, You can configure to receive alerts via email/sms.

Checkout [superlance](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance/blob/master/docs/index.rst) - Superlance is a package of plugin utilities for monitoring and controlling processes that run under supervisor.